# Why vim search is much slower than "cat fileName | grep targetText"?

Tags: search, vim, string-matching

I have a 1.4 GB text file named test.txt and I want to search a string inside the file.

I'd like to know why vim search (vim test.txt, then type `/targetText` to search the string) performs much slower than `cat test.txt | grep targetText`?

On my machine, vim search takes about several minutes to complete the search, while `cat test.txt | grep targetText` takes about several seconds to complete the search.

Comment: From `:he grep`: "Vim has two ways to find matches for a pattern: Internal and external. (...)  The internal method will be slower, because files are read into memory."

Comment: `/targetText` and `grep targetText` have vastly different purposes.

Comment: @romainl What are the vastly different purposes two different 'search' commands have apart from searching?

Comment: @syam, `/` is more adequate for situations where you don't want to know about all the matches, while `:grep` and friends are more adequate for situations where you need to review all the matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim is an editor.  It will try to load the file in memory then you can do edits on it.  Vim can edit huge files, but is not optimized for it.

On the other Hand cat and grep do not need to read the whole file in memory.

BTW you can just do `grep search file` without using cat.

Answer (score 0):

If targetText is short the delay should be caused by numerous loads from disk (necessary to search through the whole text). We should note that vim is an interactive tool and it is not designed for fast processing of gygabytes. Of course if we know in advance that our pattern match lays in many, many megabytes downstream from the current screen, we could read huge pieces from disk and in such a way get fast. But in real life Vim doesn't know how much data worth to read in once, because if we expect the pattern to be found in rather short distance, say, three lines below (agree, it's much more expected situation) then we have absolutely no reason to read huge data amounts from disk; it would be useless consumption of time and bandwidth. As Vim doesn't know a priori what amount of data to read at once, it uses some trade-off which doesn't occur to be optimal in your case.

On the opposite side, a pipeline "cat|.." bravely operates with very large pieces of data only limited by memory available to the process (ideally having once found the file it reads data in non-stop mode and sends to the pipeline). Because cat "knows" that the whole file content is needed and there is no reason to read it by small pages.

Thus, although grep and cat suck the same amount of data, the latter seeks a track on disk much less times that results in dramatic efficiency increase.

If a prefix character combination of our pattern is very frequent in the file to scan, we may also experience an efficiency advantage of grep search technique based on Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm.